# Reach Nodejs express app with external ip

Tags: node.js, express, networking

So I create a NodeJs express app which I can reach by using my local ip-address (192.168.x.x), but when I use my ISP provided Ipv4 address I got "connection timed out".

**The things that I done to make it live:**

- I disable firewall on ubuntu 16.04.
- Open port at my router.
- Even I put my local ip-address in DMZ.

If you have any suggestion please let me know!

My very simple code is here:

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/health-check', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));

app.listen(25565, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: What are the first two octets of the ISP-provided address?

Comment: 88.209.xx.xx so with this Ip address I think It must work.

Comment: Is that the address on the WAN interface of your router, and is there not other router running NAT between the WAN router and the server you are trying to reach?

Comment: I have a router so the network is looks like this:
ISP-ROUTER-LAN (where my server is) so yeah I have NAT but only one.

Comment: How did you discover the public address? Was it from a web site, or did you look at the address assigned in the router? It has become common for residential ISPs to use CGN, and a web site will give you your public address, but the address actually assigned to the router is a CGN address.

Comment: Actually I check the address from a web site and I also check at the router internet address but it is not different.

Comment: Maybe my port forwarding is bad and I did a mistake... Can you check it? Picture from port forwarding: https://ibb.co/c0747H

Comment: Your port forwarding is off-topic here. You can ask about that on [su].